# "Nested" MVVM Question

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF window that has a datagrid and a user control for a form for the fields in that datagrid. The user control and the WPF window have view models.

The user control's DataContext is bound to one of the window's view model's member field, whose value changes during the data grid's Selection Changed event.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it because I am unable to create references from the inner view model to the outer view model for some reason. Constructor injection won't work because I'm required to use default constructor only, and I can't seem to put a property injector in the right place (always getting null reference when I try to use it).

I am also unable to get my property change notification to work properly in the inner view model.

Is there a better way to wire my view models so that they automatically change the values in the user control when a new row is selected in the datagrid? I have a feeling that binding to the control's DataContext is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seems a complex/nested scenario. Looks like pretty much a normal master details scenario. Suppose you want to edit Customer data, I would have an ObservableCollection instance bind to the DataGrid, and there will be a SelectedCustomer property in the VM also. In the DataGrid you can set SelectedItem twoway bind to the SelectedCustomer property which makes SelectedCustomer always updated with your selection. Since the usercontrol has the same instance of customer as in the DataGrid row, whenever you change anything in the UC those data will get reflected in the grid. Ofcourse all those properties should fire NotifypropertyChanged.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have those in place. It is a nested scenario because the page's view model also has a reference to the detail's view model. I think I should have just one view for both the master and detail instead of separating them, so that I don't have to deal with the states of two view models.